# Do tools for building a traffic map from a pcap capture exist?

Tags: monitoring, network-discovery

I'm essentially looking for a tool that has this functionality: [SMART](http://safemap.sourceforge.net/demo/index-no-refresh.html)

The tool was written by Cisco but hasn't been updated in almost a decade. I tried running it and while it works for small pcap files, it throws segmentation faults when you feed it something substantial.

Is anyone aware of another tool that could draw this kind of graph from a pcap?

Comment: Unfortunately, software recommendations have been voted off topic here. You can consider asking this on the [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: This is also a network professionnal question about a tool to replace a faulty one. The day I will look for such a skilled tool I will look on a professionnal grade web server and not on a discussion group. This web server exists and it is here :). This isn't an open call to discuss the advantages of different commercial solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, polls and product recommendations are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. If you have the required reptutation (currently 20+) please ask in our dedicated [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/) where you are free to ask a wider variety of questions.

Comment: See this previous answer on a pretty similar question http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/17495/13986 .

Comment: @danielAzuelos Thanks for the help. I actually saw that post and the well explained answer but that is for someone who was trying to get a topology diagram from a capture, which of course can't be done, at least not from a capture from a single point. What I'm looking for on the other hand is a simple map of "who is talking to who and over which protocols", which you can extrapolate from a packet dump (just hoping I won't have to end up coding something ugly myself, would rather a pretty and time-saving solution ;).